# Bordering Sharply in MetroStyle TAB in Metro Tabbed Layout in Windows C# Form Applications

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-metro

How can I sharply differentiate between two metro style Tabs and Provide en elevated 3D look in the metro style Tab.
Which Property to modify. I have tried modifying the border property but no effect.

TAB1 and TAB 2 appears to be a single tab.

Please see the image

[image]

Comment: _"...`metro` style Tabs and Provide en elevated `3D` look in the metro style Tab..."_ - Metro is by definition **not 3D**.  You might want to consider styling the focused tab _color-wise_ so that it is more apparent. 3D not required.  Check out the [MS XAML Controls Gallery app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/p/xaml-controls-gallery/9msvh128x2zt?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)

Comment: ok may be not 3D but how to differentiate between tabs